# JQuery live() function stops firing after css transition

Tags: jquery, events, html, static, absolute

Here is what I have:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="container">

    </div>
</div>

#container
{  
    transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
    top: 0%;
    z-index: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

}
#wrapper
{
     width: 2048px;
     height: 1536px;
     position: absolute;
}
```

The container div holds the content with hotspots with tap events on them. The wrapper is used to move the content left and right with css animation. The animation is working great, however, after applying this animation:

```
$('#wrapper').css('-webkit-transition','-webkit-transform 0s ease-out').css('-webkit-transform','translate3d(' + '2048px,0px,0)');
```

the hotspot events inside the container div do not respond....I'm thinking the statically positioned hotspots are now off. Is there a better way to achieve this?

---

@Connor:  Here is a fiddle link, however its not a working replica, but hopefully its enough for you to get an idea of how its set up....
http://jsfiddle.net/dTVqx/

---

### another update: I added borders to the hotspots & The hotspots do appear to be in the right place and on top, so it seems maybe the events are being disabled somehow after the css animation is executed??

Here is my current live() call:

```
$('.modal').live('tap',function(event) 
{
  ...
}

I ALSO DID TRY on()

$(".modal").on("tap", function()
{
...
}

but on() does not work at all, even before the transition
```

Comment: you know that you can use a JS object to set several attributes in `.css()` instead of calling it over and over again, eg: `$(selector).css({height: 100px, width: 100px});`

Comment: @connor : I added fiddle link

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the live() call any where in your fiddle, none the less, live() has been deprecated as of 1.7.  Try using the on() and off() functions instead and see if that produces the functionality you are looking for?

Comment: Yes my fidddle is not a complete working replica. I do know live() is deprecated, however on() does not work at all even before mt animation. I added my  live() and on() calls above:

Comment: $(".modal").on("tap", function() ---- Are you using jQuery mobile?